# Balancing reaction between lead(II) sulfide and ozone

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I came across a question, asking to check whether the reaction is correctly balanced or not and one of the options were

$$\ce{PbS + 2O3 -> PbSO4 + O2}.\tag{R1}$$

The reaction seems to be a balanced one (atoms-balanced and charge-balanced).
But my teacher told that it is not the correct balanced reaction.
The reason given to me was that ozone breaks into $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{[O]}$ as:
$$
\begin{align}
\ce{O3 &-> O2 + [O]}\tag{R1.1}\\
\ce{PbS + [O] &-> PbSO4}\tag{R1.2}
\end{align}
$$

Hence, the correct one is

$$\ce{PbS + 4 O3 -> PbSO4 + 4 O2}.\tag{R2}$$

But both reactions seem to be balanced and should depend on the conditions.
Am I thinking right? Or the reaction always proceed in this way only? If so, then why?

Comment: Formal balancing is one thing and reaction mechanism another thing. If you think that any O atom can oxidize PbS, than correct balancing would have no O2 Left. And you would not need O3 at all in the first place.

Comment: It's perfectly balanced, but that doesn't mean it's the right reaction that actually takes place. How you're supposed to know that for this problem is, I have no idea...